# Strange computer behavior

Tags: windows, boot, power-supply, bsod, hibernate

It is really hard to briefly describe what is happening with my computer in the title. Thus I will try to explain it as detailed as I can below.

Turning on the computer after it has been turned off for several hours (power supply on, computer off), the MSI bios graphic appears on the screen, and the computer turns off after a few seconds. The next time the computer is turned on, it results in either an "automatic windows 10 repair" or a blue screen 0xc0000001. The computer is usually turned on successfully, but once it happened to me that the third startup of the computer resulted in problems with my graphics card (the system cannot verify the digital signature of the driver). I was sure I had installed the correct drivers but to make sure I ran "sfc / scannow" which found some errors and successfully fixed them. The next computer startups as I said are going well (and the computer is stable).

**What am I sure and what is worth mentioning?**

- the graphics card is not damaged, I got it from a friend and we tested it thoroughly on different PCs
- this computer had recently installed windows 10, before its installation I reformatted all disks, and the disk on which the system was installed also had a GPT partition formatted
- RAM sticks are also working (memtest shows one error per 4 passes of the test, however, it is only a warning related to hammer bit flops)
- my previous GPU card was burned, for this reason I also replaced it with a new one (these are suspicions, but when I checked with a multimeter and looked at the card inside, it leaves me no illusions)
- the temperatures in my PC are appropriate, the processor almost never exceeds 56 degrees Celsius, the graphics card showed a maximum of 72 degrees Celsius under maximum load and stress tests

**What do I suspect?**

- this error looks a bit like something related to the power supply (I'm not sure how to test the power supply, so I ordered a new one that will arrive in 2 days). In this case, it is also possible that it is the culprit of burning my old graphics card. I suspect this because it seems strange to me that the computer only after some time of inactivity has problems with turning on (maybe some problem with the capacitor?).
- it's hard for me to believe that the problem lies in the disk / operating system, since everything was reformatted and reinstalled. I would like to add that the next "sfc / scannow" runs do not show any errors anymore "

**What I want to ask?**
Could this be related to the errors that were fixed by sfc /scannow tool? Honestly saying I'm writing this post after fixing these errors.

Can you advise me on what to do in such a situation, possibly share your experiences and suspicions?
I would be very grateful.

**Update 22/11/22**
I did performed a Windows 10 system repair, the system files were reinstalled and Windows.old directory was created. I thought that it would fix the issue. However this evening the same thing occured again (first pc start-up failed, and others were okay). I managed to check the event log for some troubleshooting, I downloaded the WinDBG software for checking the contents of dump file and this is the output:

**Dump file contents:**

INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR (a0)   The power policy manager experienced a fatal error.
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000000010e, The disk subsystem returned corrupt data while reading from the hibernation file.
Arg2: 000000000000000a
Arg3: 000000000000f116, Incorrect checksum
Arg4: 000000000000723e, Previous disk read's checksum

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xa0_10e_0xa_HIBERSTACK_INIT_FAILED_IMAGE_stornvme.sys   IMAGE_NAME:  stornvme.sys
MODULE_NAME: stornvme
FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80767ff0000 stornvme

What is strange to me is that it looks like the problem is related to the hibernation file and it is weird, because when I checked the power settings of my PC, the hibernation is disabled... Any ideas?

**Update 25/11/22**

Now the computer failed to boot with some other kind of error.

**Dump file contents:**

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (ef)
A critical system process died
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffe08d0302d080, Process object or thread object
Arg2: 0000000000000000, If this is 0, a process died. If this is 1, a thread died.
Arg3: 0000000000000000, The process object that initiated the termination.
Arg4: 0000000000000000

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

Comment: Have you tested the disk, regardless of beliefs? If even one "sfc /scannow" run has shown errors in the past, then they must have come from _somewhere,_ very likely the disk. Reformatting it / reinstalling the OS doesn't make such problems go away, i.e. it only fixes the existing damage but doesn't prevent it from reoccurring.

Comment: @user1686 thanks for so quick response. Could you please provide me some instructions how should I test the disk? :)

Comment: SFC might or might not have fixed all the problems. To ensure coherence, I usually advise to also do a [Repair Install of Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as a major Windows upgrade and keeps all apps & data.

Comment: One more strange thing, I have just noticed that after running sfc /scannow etc now there is something strange with my usb devices. They appear and are recognized in device manager but not in the system. For instance usb headphones and usb drives. I also noticed that a few services are down, one is windows audio so that is the case, but why are they down? Im trying to repair the windows right now directly from mediatool, lets check...

Comment: I have yet to have sfc or dism fix anything EVER.. even when it tells me that it fixed something.  People often tell people to run it when they have no idea what a problem is but (as mentioned) I have yet to see it fix anything myself OR here on SU and have someone come back here and report that it worked.  I agree with @harrymc .. I have had repair install fix my problems.. and sometime identify that I have a hardware problem (because the problem persists).  #1 backup your stuff.  #2 repair install keeping everything. You have nothing to lose after that.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I did the things that you mentioned. Could you please check the update from 22/11/22 that I provided? Thanks

Comment: Back to what @user1686 suggested.  It sounds like a disk or cable problem to me but all we can do is guess based on experience.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas which cable are you talking about? I forgot to add that I'm using M2 disk. Do you know how can I test disk for such problems?

Comment: Shutdown via "fast startup" is actually implemented as logout followed by hibernation, so that's what you're probably seeing there.

Comment: Should i disable it then?

Comment: No, that's just papering over the issue. The hibernation image getting corrupted isn't the problem; it's a symptom of the broader problem that _various data_ on your system disk is repeatedly getting corrupted in general – so if it's not the hibernation image, then it'll be your documents, or your Registry (or one of the OS files during the regular upgrade).

Comment: @user1686 do you know what can I do with it?

Comment: @user1686 new error has just appeared... im thinking of replacing the disks, im also wondering if it can be related to the psu.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same bug reports and here's what happened.
At first it had been only 0xA0 codes then it started spewing out completly random codes.
After some time it stopped just to return back 2 weeks later with 0xA0, exception codes relating to kernel and memory (codes: 0x3D, 0x55, 0x7E).
Fast foward and SSD randomly failed overnight so I replaced it and most of errors disappear (it's weird since both tech service and chkdsc didn't find a problem with it).

It all led to kernel.
So I downloaded most recent drives on USB-stick, unisntalled all drives on PC  and installed new one's from USB-stick and problem as for now doesn't exist.
I'd also recommend [downloading OCCT](https://www.ocbase.com/) to do stress tests for PSU and other hardware (do mind they might not yield accurate result)